# php pdo prepared statment and transitions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to write a function that is supposed to receive any MySQL statement and apply it,

The basic idea is not to repeat needed code to write to Database, well what is needed to connect to Database is creating new PDO object, starting a transaction and preparing a statement, binding values to it, executing it,

so every time I want to access the Database I don't have to repeat these steps,

Here is a function that does that :

==============================================================================================

```
 protected function applyQuery($statement, $bindparameters , &$values , $selectStatement, &$result){
    try{
       $dbh = DataBase::setConnection();// new PDO("MySQL= .....");
       $dbh->beginTransaction();
       $stmt = $dbh->prepare($statement);

       if($bindparameters == true){
           foreach($values as $key => $value){
               $stmt->bindValue($key, $value);
           }
       }
       $stmt->execute();
       $dbh->commit();
       if($selectStatement == TRUE){
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       }
        }catch (PDOException $e){
            $dbh->rollBack();
        throw DataBase::$Errors[0];
       }

}
```

============================================================================================

$statement = the desired statement (e.g 'SELECT * from users WHERE username = :username')///

$bindparameters = do we need to bind values (in this examples yes) so its value TRUE///

&$values = array by reference in this case equals = (':username' => 'User');///

$selectStatement = tells if using SELECT in statement ,in this case TRUE///

$result = array by reference in this case the final fetch result will be stored in it///

so in this example we get the following call to the function : 
applyQuery('SELECT * from users WHERE username = :username', TRUE ,array(':username' => 'User') , TRUE , result )

My question is : will this code work ?
is the logical sequence of what it does and should do make sense ?
whats the difference between $stmt->execute and $dbh->commit ?
is omitting any line will cause failure to achieve the desired result

Please understand that I did lookup what is PDO and read a lot but unable to answer these questions!

Comment: Sorry, but you make a common mistake: you try to abstract the abstraction.

Comment: I cant understand you ?, all I need to do is send a statement from multiple files

Comment: Sure, that is daily business. But there is no reasons to make such a "meta function". Use a central connection object and code the single queries using that object and the functions offered by the database abstraction class. You will just run into problems with your approach when it comes to special cases.

Comment: can you at least explain to me and tell me if there is error

Comment: Sorry, but it really is hard to see what you actually ask. I spot about 8 different questions in there. And all should be answered by the documentation (for example difference of `execute()` vs. `commit()`). Sorry, I will not invest half an hour into picking this apart. As said: it is a dead end anyway.

Comment: Are you able to at least sumerize your question? And you need to adjust the formatting of the post. Youve code blocked more than you intended which is making it hard to read

Comment: I will try to fix it in the upcoming time,it basically will allow me always to use one function for any given statement

Comment: @TamerKadmany I don't know why you're doing what you're trying to do... your code above doesn't really save you a whole lot, nor simplify much of anything.  It sounds like you would benefit from an ORM.

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: that way I don't have to repeat what I have written